# Was my meta question valid or not?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, per-site-meta, specific-site

I asked a question on meta.hinduism.SE which is as follows:

- [Are there any strong evidence that Hinduism religion is an ancient one?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/93)

I asked this question on meta instead of main site (i.e Hinduism.SE) because of a thought that it might end up with bad answers and long discussion. So, I asked on meta as there is a tag available as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (*though I am not sure to which extent I am right about the tag*)

I know my post is not related to improving main site but still asked on meta as it is not a strict site and thought users can have discussion on that topic (*I mean the above question*).

Some of the examples of the posts which are not related to their main site are:

- [Funny / Useless / Horrible code from Magento Extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/2960)

Which seems to be popular and good discussion on meta.magento.SE, then why not my question on meta.hinduism.SE?

Comment: Meta is for discussions *about the site*, not about the *topic of the site*. You discuss things like 'should questions about the history of hinduism be allowed on the site'?

Comment: That the Magento community is using their Meta for 'fun' questions is not a good example here; if that community is tolerating such questions in their Meta, then that may be their choice but it is not what Meta is *intended* for.

Comment: Already answered :  http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/261/are-there-any-strong-evidence-that-hinduism-religion-is-an-ancient-one#comment680_261

Comment: @Mr.Alien no offense to your explanation in the chat room. I just thought to confirm directly from SE network. I hope you didn't mind.

Comment: @Mr_Green nah its fine :) you have a doubt, and you are always free to get others opinion, I edited my comment and linked to a comment which explains the reason for the closure

Comment: +1 for having a misunderstanding, seeking to find out what you misunderstood, and then seeming to truly be interested in learning from the answers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks :). To be frank, I was shocked with the rain of downvotes. I was thinking what wrong did I ask here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Meta sites are there to discuss the main site. The `discussion` tag is used to handle discussions on questions about the scope of a site, or what kind of behaviour the community thinks is appropriate, etc.

Example questions would be:

- Are questions about the history of *main subject* acceptable?
- Should [] be merged with [] or are they distinct subjects?

etc.

The Magento example you found is flying in the face of the intended usage of Meta. We don't want to dictate how a community should use their Meta, but you cannot use that as justification for asking similar questions on other child Meta sites.

Comment: I am not comparing things here.. but when having a loose discussion like "unicorns" seems valid then why not something useful? _no offense to unicorns_

Comment: @Mr_Green: Different communities may have different levels of tolerance for fun or other off-topic topics. This varies from site to site.